# Unix header and footer matching patterns condition

Tags: shell, unix, kernel

I need to move my text files from processing folder to backup folder by reading the files in directory, each text file contains header, footer and other records. before moving to backup I need check that header should start with 01 and footer should start 99. If the condition satisfies i should move otherwise skip the current file and continue with other files. How to write a condition to check the 1st line should strat with 01 and last line should start with 99.

Please help me..Thanks in advance.

Sreeni

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes, I need sample logic for this.

Comment: read the man pages for head, tail and grep, try to do it yourself, then come back with some specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

```
cat file | head -1 | grep "^01"   #check the first line start with 01
cat file | tail -1 | grep "^99"   #check the last line start with 99
```

If "^" doesn't work just replace it with "/>". Both mean starting with.

Answer (score 0):

you can use awk to do it, first write a awk script,e.g. t.awk

```
NR==1{if($1~/^01/)print}
END{if($1~/^99/)print}
```

and then,use `awk -f t.awk your_file_name`

hope to help you.